# ActiveRecord except one with specific id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this search query:

```
  @ebm_entry = @patient.ebm_entries.find(params[:id])
  @ebm_entries = @patient.ebm_entries.where("created_at::date = ?", @ebm_entry.created_at.to_date)
```

`@ebm.entry` returns the entry with the id `40`
and `@ebm.entries` returns the entries with the ids `40` and `42`

Now im trying to remove the `@ebm.entry` from the `@ebm.entries`:

I tried:

```
@ebm.entries =

@patient.ebm_entries.where("create....).not(id: @ebm_entry.id)
@patient.ebm_entries.where("create....).except(@ebm_entry)
```

and

```
@patient.ebm_entries.where("created_at::date = ?", @ebm_entry.created_at.to_date  "&& id !=" @ebm_entry.id )
```

But somehow i always get a error! What do i wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this

```
@patient.ebm_entries.where('id != ?', @ebm_entry.id).where("created_at::date = ?", @ebm_entry.created_at.to_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

in **Rails 4** you could use **[where.not](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions)**

```
@results = @patient.ebm_entries
#remove unwanted record
@results.where.not(id: @ebm_entry.id)
#more results filtering
@results.where("created_at::date = ?", @ebm_entry.created_at.to_date)
```